# 8051 Port 0 as input query

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, port

I want to use the Port 0 of 8051 as input. Is it required to use external pull-up resistors? Or its only required when Port 0 is to be configured as output?

Comment: This is dependent on your input circuit.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on your input circuit. Does it provide a good high and low signals? If they are left 'floating' at any time the input can be affected by stray noise. This will appear as random values on the port.